# PostFix | SMTP Server

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, smtp

What is a Post Fix, Can some one explain in a very Simple Language.

I have a dedicated server, what is needed to Install on it so that I can Convert it into SMTP, with authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Postfix is an SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol) server. Look at this page to read more about [SMTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP).

Your question can not be answered in its current form. You need to read a lot more about this topic and if you have any specific problem, we can help.